# VScode - tab moves focus from editor area even when disabled

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using VS Code when pressing tab in the editor area, even though `Tab Key moves focus` is toggled off (It is not showing in the status bar), the tab key still moves focus, I even disabled the keyboard shortcut for the toggle.

I tried to tab the text but instead the tab key moved the focus to another pane.

Edit:
here is the output of `Help: About`:

```
Version: 1.85.0 (user setup)
Commit: af28b32d7e553898b2a91af498b1fb666fdebe0c
Date: 2023-12-06T20:48:09.019Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

Output when pressing tab using `Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`:

```
2023-12-12 15:06:14.558 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-12-12 15:06:14.559 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving Tab
2023-12-12 15:06:14.559 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 12 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
2023-12-12 15:06:14.559 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Tab, keyCode: 9, key: Tab
2023-12-12 15:06:14.559 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Tab, keyCode: 2 ('Tab')
2023-12-12 15:06:14.559 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving Tab
2023-12-12 15:06:14.559 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 12 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
```

Comment: interesting... might want to also raise an issue ticket (use `Help > Raise Issue` in VS Code menubar). If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.

Comment: @starball here is the open issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200839